# Flask handle button click

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am trying to do a website to read CSV file and be able to view the data, edit, delete or add new rows/columns. I am able to read the data from a file and view it. I upload a CSV file using a form and then read the data and view it in a page. An example of data looks like this: [image: this]

Here is the html code for the picture above:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Home page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<table class="table">
    <tr class="table__header">
        <th class="table__cell"> Row </th>
        {% for header in data[0] %}
        <th class="table__cell"> {{ header }} </th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for row in data[1:] %}
    <tr class="table__row">
        <td>{{loop.index}}</td>
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td class="table__cell"> {{ cell }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td width="130">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Edit</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete btn-sm">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see I created two buttons, an edit and a delete button for each of the rows. I just do not know how to handle the click for the buttons. If for example I click edit then I want to get redirected to a new page where I can edit the particular row I choose to edit. If instead I click on delete then it will just delete the element. How can I handle the buttons? Can I only handle buttons via forms? or is there other ways? I am very new to Flask (have just programmed in it for 3-4 days) so I have no clue how to do. I tried to search for an awnser but I do not quite understand and I do not get anything similar to my project. Please help.

Comment: you have to assign urls to buttons but you have only `href=""`. And you should add unique information in url to recognize row in Flask - ie. `href="/edit/1"` for first row - and flask should have function with `route("/edit/<number>")`. And the same with other button `href="/delete/1` and `route("/delet/<number>")`. You don't have to use `form` if you use `<a>`.

Comment: I think you should find it in any tutorial - every page needs some buttons (or rather links in your situation). It doesn't have to be button/link to `edit` or `delete` but for `next page` or `next post` in blog. ie, [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) shows `microblog`